# Unzip a single ".zip" file into multiple directories as per the name of the files contained in zip file - Linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I have the following scenario :-
My Zip file = abcd.zip
its content :-

1. a.txt
2. b.txt
3. c.txt

Now i want to unzip this zip file into folder a/ , b/ and c/ . (Txt files can be of upper or lower case)

So basically i am looking to unzip a file into their own specified directory .

Comment: Your zip file doesn't contain directories ? I mean does it always contain only .txt files ?

Comment: yes , it does not contain any directories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Unzip your archive into the current directory.
2. execute the following command:
   `` for i in `ls -1 *.txt | sed 's/\.[a-z]*//g'`; do mkdir $i; mv $i.* $i/; done ``

Answer (score 0):

You could try as following,

Put this script in the same directory as the zip file and pass the name of the zip file as the argument to the script.

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

name="$1"

list="$(unzip -l "${name}" | sed -n '/---/,/---/{ /----/d; p; }' | awk '{print $4}')"

for file in ${list}
do
   dirnam=$(basename "${file}" ".txt")
   mkdir -p "${dirnam}"
   unzip "${name}" -d "${dirnam}" "${file}"
done
```

example:

```
/home/abis> ./unzip.sh test.zip 
Archive:  test.zip
 extracting: 1/1.txt                 
Archive:  test.zip
 extracting: 2/2.txt                 
Archive:  test.zip
 extracting: 3/3.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's all .txt:
`zipinfo -1 abc.zip | while read line;do mkdir -p ${line%.txt}; unzip abc.zip $line -d ${line%.txt};done`

For any extension (considering everything after last dot as extension):
`zipinfo -1 abc.zip | while read line;do mkdir -p ${line%.*}; unzip abc.zip $line -d ${line%.*};done`

For a list of extensions:
`zipinfo -1 abc.zip | while read line;do mkdir -p ${line%.?(txt|jpg|gif)}; unzip abc.zip $line -d ${line%.?(txt|jpg|gif)};done`

The last option requires extglob, which is disabled by default. So run `shopt extglob` to see if it's on or off. `shopt -s extglob`enable it and `shopt -u extglob`disable.